# child objects update issue - Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

Child objects recreated and not updated every time I update the parent object,
the parent object is working perfect but the child objects `@OneToOne` cascade:all recreated and not updated.

Parent Object:

```
public class Account  extends PersonalInformation {
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="activatedDate")
    private Date activatedDate;

    @Column(name="expiredDate")
    private Date expiredDate;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="priv_id")
    private Privilege priv;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="access_id")
    private AccessPoint access;
}
```

Child Object:

```
public class AccessPoint {
    // % by default from everywhere;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="host")
    private String host;

    @Column(name="port")
    private String port;

    @Column(name="country")
    private String country;

    @Column(name="town")
    private String town;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="account_id")
    private Account account
}
```

Comment: did you named the id of class AccessPoint with the name specified in the joinCokumn anootation?

Comment: check the post now :@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) @JoinColumn(name="account_id") private Account account;

Comment: Both ids are named by default. You should set it names like the orther attributes.

Comment: can you make an example because i didnt get it..

Comment: please, look this example: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation

Comment: Do you load your child objects, while getting a parent? Or are they lazy initialized?